# solve this 1st order linear equation

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

$$(x+3)^2\frac{dy}{dx}=6-12y-4xy=6-y(12+4x)$$

a. Write it in standard form.
$$\frac{dy}{dx}+\frac{12+4x}{(x+3)^2}y=\frac6{(x+3)^2}$$

b. What is the integrating factor?
$$\frac{12+4x}{(x+3)^2} = \frac14x+\frac34 \implies$$
$$IF=e^{\int{\frac14x+\frac34}}=e^{\frac18x^2+\frac34x}$$

c. Integrate the DE subject to $y(0)=1$.
$$e^{\frac18x^2+\frac34x}\frac{dy}{dx}+ye^{\frac18x^2+\frac34x}(\frac14x+\frac34)=\frac{6e^{\frac18x^2+\frac34x}}{(x+3)^2} \implies$$
$$ye^{\frac18x^2+\frac34x}=\int{\frac{6e^{\frac18x^2+\frac34x}}{(x+3)^2}}+c$$

I have done this problem a few times and now getting kind of stuck. Please check my standard form and integrating factor.

Right now if everything else is correct I cannot solve the integral. Any help appreciated.

Comment: $\frac{12+4x}{(x+3)^2}\neq 0.25x+0.75$.

Comment: @vadim123 can you share what it is? I got that result through long division.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$(x+3)^2\frac{dy}{dx}=6-4y(3+x)$$
$$(x+3)^2\frac{dy}{dx}+4y(3+x)=6$$
Multiply by $(x+3)^2$
$$(x+3)^4y'+4y(3+x)^3=6(x+3)^2$$
$$((x+3)^4y)'=6(x+3)^2$$
Integrate
$$(x+3)^4y=2(x+3)^3+C$$
$$y(x)=\frac 2 {(x+3)}+\frac C {(x+3)^4}$$

---

As pointed out in the comment this line is not correct
$$\frac{12+4x}{(x+3)^2} = \frac14x+\frac34 $$
This is correct
$$\frac{12+4x}{(x+3)^2} = \frac 4 {x+3}$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{12+4x}{(x+3)^2}=\frac{4(x+3)}{(x+3)^2}=\frac{4}{x+3}$$

Comment: Wow. Tunnel vision really got to me on this one. Thank you.

Comment: Glad to be of service.